# Use rational zero theorem to find real zeros of $2x^3-3x^2-x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I am to use the rational zero theorem to find the real zeros of $2x^3-3x^2-x+1$.

The provided answers are $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

I was able to get $\frac{1}{2}$ on my own but I do not see how the other two were found.

In my textbook I am told I can find candidate 0's by taking the quotient of factors of p over factors of q where p is the constant term and q is the leading coefficient.

In this case p = factors of 1 = $\pm1$ and q = factors of 2 = $\pm1, 2$. Dividing combinations of p/q I get $\pm1$ and $\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

I then tried substituting for x each of those 4 combinations within the function $2x^3-3x^2-x+1$ and found that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a zero.

How/why are $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ also zeros and how could I determine that from the rational zero theorem only? This last part is important since the chapter in my textbook and section of exercises specifically states I am to use this theorem to determine the real zeros.

Comment: As $\frac12$ is a root, then $2x-1$ is a factor of the polynomial. What's the other factor?

Comment: Use Long Division Rule or Synthetic Division Rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** By rational root theorem you get that $1/2$ is a root to the cubic and so $2x-1$ is a factor of the cubic. Applying division algorithm, we get,
$$2x^3-3x^2-x+1=(2x-1)(x^2-x-1)=0$$Now can you solve the quadratic $x^2-x-1=0$?

Comment: I follow how you arrive at a new factor `$x^2-x-1$` but I don't see how this gets me to `$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$`. If I solve `$x^2-x-1$=0` I get `\pm\sqrt{x+1}`?

Comment: (guess markup doesn't work in comments)

Comment: @DougFir It works fine, but you can't use back ticks.  $\pm\sqrt{x+1}$ is not a solution to the quadratic.  You don't want any $x$'s.

Comment: @DougFir:  use the quadratic formula with $a=1, b=-1, $ and $c=-1$

Comment: I got it now, thanks! So, in order to look for this in future is the idea to look out for any roots that are fractions, and then to calculate their factor by multiplying out the fraction?

Comment: @DougFir The roots don't have to be fractions. When Anand formulated his answer, he got that $x=\frac{1}{2}\Longrightarrow x-\frac{1}{2}=0\Longrightarrow 2x-1=0$.You want to find the roots using the rational root theorem and then get them into the form $ax+b=0$ and use polynomial long division, i.e, the division algorithm to find the remaining factors of the polynomial in question.